# The code written using apollonius theorem of triangle is giving a value of the median which does'nt seems the right one

Tags: python, geometry

I was working on a program that takes values of each lenght on a triangle. And shound print the value of the median of that triangle. I have written the code using apollonius theorem of triangle. The program runs and also gives values. But when I calculate them manually. I find a totaly different value. Can anyone help me find the bug ?

I tried the apollonius theorem of triangle for the code. But can't find any problem in my code. But it still gives a wrong value.

```
#not working
#m = median of triangle
#formula ==> p^2 + h^2 = 2(m^2 + h^2/2)
import math
import time
for _ in range(1,100):
    b = float(input("Enter the value of the Base : "))
    p = float(input("Enter the value of the Perpendicular : "))
    h = float(input("Enter the value of the Hypertenuse : "))

    lhs = (p**2)+(h**2)
    print("lhs "+str(lhs))
    
    half_of_hypertenuse_with_square = (h/2)**2
    print("half H "+str(half_of_hypertenuse_with_square))
    
    pre_result = lhs/half_of_hypertenuse_with_square
    print("pre_result "+str(pre_result))
    

    semi_result = pre_result/2
    print("semi_result "+str(semi_result))

    final_result = math.sqrt(semi_result)
    print("result "+str(final_result))
```

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I get your notations right, but shouldn't the formula be `p^2 + h^2 = 2(m^2 + (b/2)^2)` ? And this: `pre_result = lhs/half_of_hypertenuse_with_square` ; why a **division** ??? To sum it all, your calculations are incoherent with your formula, which I doubt anyway.

Comment: Well then. I must try out that again. That same thing clicks me. And I changed it several times. So maybe that's why it's h/2 not (b/2)^2. Thanks for your response. It helps a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fixed version; I renamed the sides (perpendicular and hypotenuse only make sense if your triangle is rectangle, in which case Pythagoras theorem would be simpler to use), fixed the formula and the calculations:

```
# formula ==> a^2 + c^2 = 2(m^2 + (b/2)^2)
import math
import time

for _ in range(1, 100):
    b = float(input("Enter the length of the Base : "))
    a = float(input("Enter the length of the second side : "))
    c = float(input("Enter the length of the third side : "))

    lhs = (a ** 2) + (c ** 2)
    print(f"lhs : {lhs}")

    squared_half_base = (b / 2) ** 2
    print(f"Squared half base : {squared_half_base}")

    pre_result = lhs / 2 - squared_half_base
    print(f"pre_result : {pre_result}")

    final_result = math.sqrt(pre_result)
    print(f"result {final_result}")
```

Edit: you might want to round the result with `round(final_result, 3)`.